# If $p,q$ distinct primes with $p,q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, show that $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {pq}$ is solveable

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I can't seem to get anywhere with this problem. Any hints would be much appreciated:

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes satisfying $p, q \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. Show that the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod {pq}$ has a solution.

Comment: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Oh man. So it's as simple as saying: We have that there is an $x_1$ and a $x_2$ such that $x_1 \equiv (-1)^{1/2} \bmod {p}$ and $x_2 \equiv (-1)^{1/2} \bmod {q}$, so by the CRT we have that there is an $x$ such that $x \equiv (-1)^{1/2} \bmod {pq}$?

Comment: You need to elaborate that a bit more when turning in, but basically it is as simple.

Comment: I will. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Silly question for Daniel: can you use CRT even if the conguences are not linear?

Comment: @GIAN, if you want Daniel to see your question, you have to put an at-sign in front of his name.

Answer (score 1):

By supplemental laws of quadratic reciprocity, we know that $-1$ is a square mod $p$ exactly when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. So we know there exist $x_p$ such that $x_p^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ and $x_q$ such that $x_q^2 \equiv -1 \pmod q$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a solution $x$ to the system of congruences
$$\begin{align}
x &\equiv x_p \pmod p \\
x &\equiv x_q \pmod q
\end{align}$$
and that this $x$ is defined $\bmod {pq}$. Since $x^2 \equiv -1$ both $\bmod p$ and $\bmod q$, this $x$ is the solution you're looking for. $\diamondsuit$